# Is it safe to add medication in a fish tank if there is no sick* fishes?

Tags: health, aquarium, diseases, goldfish

My water conditions aren't the best, yet, my fishes are doing their best so far. I want to put a fungus and fin rot remedy in the fish tank but none of them have it (at least  I don't think so). 
Two-three fishes each have a tumor/lump. One-two fish have a dark red area on their gills and two fishes has a swimming bladder disorder (one is permanent). I have 6 fishes in total.

Here are my water conditions:

pH - 6.6-7
Nitrate - 200+ppm (may be due to poor filter)
Nitrite - 0-.5ppm
Hardness - 300+ppm
Chlorine - 0 ppm
Alkalinity - 0-40ppm

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you want to medicate a tank when fishes are not sick ?

Answer (score 0):

It's safe in a controlled environment; when you use medication in your aquarium you need to control the parameters and use these methods:

- Change 40 % of the tank's water volume, once a week
- Put activated carbon in the filter to remove the surplus medication from the water

**BUT FIRST** try to not use medication; look for alternative methods, for example:

- Termoteraphy
- Aloe vera
- Alimentation change (green peas)

Comment: please explain how this is done and add some sources where i can learn more about your suggested treatments.